# How to really-really rescan media library in Banshee?

Tags: banshee

I made a few edits to track information in Banshee's File System Queue playlist, and it appeared nice. However, the Artists box (in the middle of the screen) contained old information (as it was before my edit).

I thought this would get fixed if I select `Tools -> Rescan Media Library`. I got a brief message with '100% complete' status, however list of artists (which was modified and changed) remains as it was.

I have no clue what this means and how to really re-scan the library.

Answer (score 9):

First, you must erase the file that save the library information, this file is:

`~/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db`

After that, you can scan media in Banshee and you will have all the new metadata.

Comment: This approach works, but you will also lose your playlists in the process. Be sure to export them before you delete the database file. You can then import them again after the database has been recreated.

Comment: I had a situation where my rescan of the music library would stop after about 100 to 150 - the info box in the corner vanished rapidly. I moved my music library out of the way, and did this and restarted with a new library - then imported. Success! Thank you! (I didn't have any playlists to save.)

Comment: not yet working yet...nice idea though.

Answer (score 2):

Tracks in the file system queue aren't technically part of the media library. It's simply a way to enqueue tracks without having to import them. You may need to 'requeue' them after updating the metadata.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "aren't technically part of the media library". If they are not, then does this mean that the only way to purge incorrect (outdated) data in Banshee is to remove all tracks from its Media Library and import file locations to it again? Could you please elaborate? And please let me know how to requeue them after the update. Thanks very much for replying to my question!

Comment: I respect developers for doing a lot of stuff, but not updating file metadata if file timestamp changed looks clearly like a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that a rescan doesn't 'find' anything with Banshee 2.0.  However, if you import your media library once again (under media/import media), it will import only those files that are new.   You won't get duplicates, as it compares the import against the existing files.